# Ejecutar con maven wsgen de jax-ws en un Web Service con hibernate

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse, hibernate, java-ee

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el comando `wsgen` para generar un `WSDL` y las clases `wrapper` de un `WebService`. Hice el esqueleto del web service y probe el siguiente comando:

```
wsgen -cp . administracionCheques.services.ChequesWS -verbose -keep -wsdl
```

Todo funciono correctamente, después use hibernate para hacer mis operaciones de base de datos, y todo funciono también correctamente.

Por ultimo integre mi lógica de base de datos con `hibernate` en el `WebService` por lo que tuve que actualizar las clases wrapper ejecutando el comando mencionado, pero es en este punto donde me mando la siguiente excepción:

```
C:\Users\aahernan\eclipse-photon-workspace\administracionCheques\target\classes>wsgen -cp . administracionCheques.services.ChequesWS -verbose -keep -wsdl
administracionCheques\services\jaxws\RegistraRemesa.java
administracionCheques\services\jaxws\RegistraRemesaResponse.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.determineWebMethodUse(RuntimeModeler.java:396)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:411)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:305)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:243)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsGen.main(WsGen.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 19 more

C:\Users\aahernan\eclipse-photon-workspace\administracionCheques\target\classes>
```

Mi pregunta es **¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a wsgen donde están las clases de hibernate?**

Leí por ahí que hay que pegar los jars en la carpeta lib del proyecto para que funcione.

El problema ahí es que estoy usando `maven` por lo que esa carpeta esta vacía. Entonces mi otra pregunta es **¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutar el comando wsgen desde maven adjuntando las dependencias de hibernate?** Estoy usando eclipse.

Les dejo el código de mis archivos:
//El pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>comentado</groupId>
  <artifactId>administracionCheques</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
   <!-- Inicio Servlet y JSP-->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  <!-- Fin Servlet y JSP-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  <!-- Inicio Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Fin Hibernate -->
    <!-- inicio spring core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- fin spring core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

//ICheques.java

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

import administracionCheques.jsonVO.Respuesta;

@WebService(name = "chequesWS",targetNamespace="http://chequesWS.comentado")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT,parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface ICheques {
    @WebMethod(operationName="registraRemesa")
    public Respuesta registraRemesa(String oficioRemesa);

}
```

//ChequesWS.java

```
@WebService(name = "chequesWS",targetNamespace="http://chequesWS.comentado",serviceName = "chequesService", portName = "chequesWSPort")
public class ChequesWS implements ICheques {
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;
    @WebMethod(operationName="registraRemesa")
    public Respuesta registraRemesa(@WebParam(name="oficioRemesa") String oficioRemesa){
        System.out.println("usuario= " + wsContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());
        System.out.println("CH_servicioweb= " + wsContext.isUserInRole("CH_servicioweb"));
        String usuario=wsContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=null;
        Session session=null;
        Transaction tx=null;
        OficioRemesa oficioObj=null;
        Respuesta respuesta=null;
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            oficioObj = gson.fromJson(oficioRemesa,OficioRemesa.class);
            HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
            HibernateUtil.openSessionAndBindToThread();
            sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.doWork(new Work() {//Esta funcion con el TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED es para que haga el WITH (nolock) en las consultas
                @Override
                public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
                }
            });
            Query queryBanco = session.createQuery("FROM Catbanco as b WHERE b.cvebanco=:cveBanco ");
            queryBanco.setParameter("cveBanco", oficioObj.getCveBanco() );
            Catbanco catbanco=(Catbanco)queryBanco.uniqueResult();
            if(catbanco!=null){
                Query queryCtaBancaria = session.createQuery("FROM Cuentabancaria as cta WHERE cta.numeroctabancaria=:ctaBancaria and cta.idbanco.cvebanco=:cveBanco ");
                queryCtaBancaria.setParameter("ctaBancaria", oficioObj.getCuentaBancaria() );
                queryCtaBancaria.setParameter("cveBanco", oficioObj.getCveBanco() );
                Cuentabancaria cuentaBancaria=(Cuentabancaria)queryCtaBancaria.uniqueResult();
                if(cuentaBancaria!=null) {
                    tx=session.beginTransaction();
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    RemesaController remesaController=new RemesaController();
                    ChequeController chequeController=new ChequeController();
                    EstatusChequeController estatusChequeController=new EstatusChequeController();
                    for(Caja caja : oficioObj.getCajas()) {
                        Remesa remesa=remesaController.crear();
                        remesa.setSolicitud(oficioObj.getSolicitud() );
                        remesa.setCuentabancaria(cuentaBancaria);
                        remesa.setOrigen(oficioObj.getOrigen());
                        remesa.setCaja(caja.getCaja());
                        remesa.setFolioinicial(caja.getFolioInicial());
                        remesa.setFoliofinal(caja.getFolioFinal());
                        remesa.setQuincena(oficioObj.getQuincena());
                        remesa.setOficioentrega(oficioObj.getOficioEntrega());
                        remesa.setOficioreferencia(oficioObj.getOficioReferencia());
                        remesa.setFechaentrega( format.parse(  oficioObj.getFechaEntrega() ));
                        remesa.setUsuariocarga(usuario);
                        for(Integer numeroCheque=caja.getFolioInicial(); numeroCheque <= caja.getFolioFinal(); numeroCheque++) {
                            EstatusCheque estatusCheque=estatusChequeController.crear();
                            Cheque cheque=chequeController.crear();
                            cheque.setRemesa(remesa);
                            cheque.setNumerocheque(numeroCheque);
                            cheque.setCuentabancaria(cuentaBancaria);
                            estatusCheque.setEstatus("R");
                            estatusCheque.setFechaactualizacion(new Date());
                            estatusCheque.setUsuario(usuario);
                            estatusCheque.setIdcheque(cheque);
                            cheque.addEstatusCheque(estatusCheque);
                            remesa.addCheque(cheque);
                        }
                        session.save(remesa);
                    }
                    tx.commit();
                }else{
                    respuesta=new Respuesta(false,"No se encontro la cuenta bancaria: "+oficioObj.getCuentaBancaria());
                }//if ctabancaria
            }else{
                respuesta=new Respuesta(false,"No se encontro la clave de banco: "+oficioObj.getCveBanco() );
            }//if catbanco
            respuesta=new Respuesta(true,"Se registro la remesa exitosamente");
        }catch (BussinessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
            StackTraceElement st = e.getStackTrace()[0];
            String mensaje="Error usando patron DAO-> "+e.getClass().getCanonicalName()+" "+st.getClassName()+"/"+st.getMethodName()+" ("+st.getLineNumber()+"): "+e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(mensaje);
            respuesta=new Respuesta(false,mensaje);
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
            StackTraceElement st = e.getStackTrace()[0];
            String mensaje="Error usando hibernate-> "+e.getClass().getCanonicalName()+" "+st.getClassName()+"/"+st.getMethodName()+" ("+st.getLineNumber()+"): "+e.getMessage();
            respuesta=new Respuesta(false,mensaje);
            System.out.println(mensaje);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
            StackTraceElement st = e.getStackTrace()[0];
            String mensaje="Error General-> "+e.getClass().getCanonicalName()+" "+st.getClassName()+"/"+st.getMethodName()+" ("+st.getLineNumber()+"): "+e.getMessage();
            respuesta=new Respuesta(false,mensaje);
            System.out.println(mensaje);
        }
        System.out.println(oficioObj);
        return respuesta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a wsgen donde están las
>   clases de hibernate?

Sí, las clases, o los jar con las clases (en este caso de Hibernate), tienen que estar en `classpath`.

Por ahí podés resolverlo agregando los jars que maven te instala en la carpeta `.m2` de tu home al `wsgen` usando `-cp`.

También encontré este plugin de maven que parece resolver lo que querés hacer: https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsgen-mojo.html

Comment: Gracias, ya me funciono con este comando: `wsgen -cp ".;C:\Users\aahernan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.3.11.Final\hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar" administracionCheques.services.ChequesWS -verbose -keep -wsdl`